# misma función para diferentes botones

Tags: jquery, ajax, struts

Tengo dos botones que llaman a la misma función, pero la llamada ajax de cada uno ha de ser diferente. 
Estos son los botones:

```
<input id="anular" type="button" value="anular Factura" onclick="duplicado();" />
<input id="rectificar" type="button" value="rectificar Factura" onclick="duplicado();" />
```

La función "duplicado()" a la que llaman ambos es ésta:

```
function duplicado(){
var confirmacion = confirm("¿Desea duplicar la factura?");
if (confirmacion){
    var miarray = new Array();
    var fecha = new Date();
    var existe= false;
    var mes = fecha.getMonth() + 1;
    var anyo = fecha.getFullYear();
    if (mes == 1 || mes == 12){
        anyo = promptAnyo(mes,anyo,false);
    }
    if(anyo!=null){
        url= url + "&anyo="+anyo;
        miarray[0]=anyo;
        var mysql = new SQL("EXISTE_HUECO_NOM_BK", miarray);
        var rs = mysql.select();
        while (rs.next()) {
            rtdo = rs.getColumn('COUNT(1)');
        }

        if(rtdo>0){
            existe=true;
        }else{
            miarray[0]=anyo;
            var mysql = new SQL("NEXT_NUMNOM_BK", miarray);
            var rs = mysql.select();
            while (rs.next()) {
                rtdo = rs.getColumn('VALOR');
            }
            var maxNumNomBK = new String(anyo).substring(2,4) + <%=Constantes.LIMITE_NOM_COMBUSTIBLES%>;
            if (rtdo <= maxNumNomBK) {
                existe = true;
            }
        }

        if(!existe){
            alert("No se puede crear más nominaciones para el año "+anyo+".");
        } else {
            var newNumNom = obtenerNewNumNom(anyo);
            var url = '/sgca/cabnom/duplicarFacturaAnulacion.action?numNomDuplicado='+newNumNom+'&cabnom.numnom=${cabnom.numnom}&operation=new';//duplicarFacturaAnulacion
            $.ajax(url, {
                async:false,
                type:'post',
                success: function(data){
                    window.location='/sgca/cabnom/edit.action?operation=edit&pestanya=LINEASNOM'+'&cabnom.numnom='+newNumNom+ 
                    '&duplicada=true';
                },
                error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                    alert("Se ha producido un error a la hora de duplicar la nominación.");
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

}
En la parte final de la función donde se hace la llamda ajax, quiero usar una url distinta según el botón en el que se haga click, pero ésto no me funciona ¿Alguna idea?

```
$(':button').click(function () {
if (this.id == 'anular') {
    url= '/sgca/cabnom/duplicarFacturaAnulacion.action?numNomDuplicado='+newNumNom+'&cabnom.numnom=${cabnom.numnom}&operation=new';
}
else if (this.id == 'rectificar') {
    url= '/sgca/cabnom/rectificarFacturaAnulacion.action?numNomDuplicado='+newNumNom+'&cabnom.numnom=${cabnom.numnom}&operation=new';
}
```

});

Comment: Puedes pasarle un parámetro a la función (ese valor lo puedes "propagar" entre llamadas) para discriminar lo que quieres hacer según el valor/valores que te lleguen.

Comment: más info por favor? :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pasa el ID como parámetro en la función:

```
<input id="anular" type="button" value="anular Factura" onclick="duplicado(this.id);" />
<input id="rectificar" type="button" value="rectificar Factura" onclick="duplicado(this.id);" />
```

De este modo sabrás si viene `duplicado(anular)` o `duplicado(rectificar)`.

En la parte del javascript deberás recogerla del siguiente modo:

```
function duplicado(id){
//...
if (id == 'anular') {
    url= '/sgca/cabnom/duplicarFacturaAnulacion.action?numNomDuplicado='+newNumNom+'&cabnom.numnom=${cabnom.numnom}&operation=new';
}
else if (id == 'rectificar') {
    url= '/sgca/cabnom/rectificarFacturaAnulacion.action?numNomDuplicado='+newNumNom+'&cabnom.numnom=${cabnom.numnom}&operation=new';
}
```

}

Comment: Justo lo estaba poniendo !!